# Get access to active current user folder in macOS in Terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

**My goal is to be able make a newFolder inside active user folder.**

This question maybe be simple for most but I could not find the answer I needed, I have a navigating question or where I am located right now in terminal.

It could be I am in deferent level or folder and I would not like just use `cd ..` or `cd folderName` to navigate to active user level. I want type a path to bring my directly to active user folder, and then I can use `mkdir newFolder`, the issue is here I want reusable code, I could hard code my username but this code would work just for me, and you cannot use my code to navigate to your active user folder. What I am trying to learn is a way to reaching the active folder with reusable code regardless where I am located in Terminal or in which level I am.

Comment: Does "_active user folder_" mean "_user's home directory_"? ... Does the unix-standard `~` or `${HOME}` work?

Comment: No, I used `${HOME}` but it said: `permission denied` @Attie

Comment: ... Did you try `cd "${HOME}"`? (`${HOME}` is a variable, which should expand to the path of your home directory... you can pass that to a command like `cd` as an argument)

Comment: or just `cd` with no arguments?

Comment: @glennjackman ... or that - but it's a bit more "_magic_" for new users, and you can't use that with other things (like `ls` vs `ls "${HOME}"`)

Comment: @Attie: I was missing `cd`, now it works, thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Please feel free to answer your own question!

Comment: To emphasize what @Attie was eluding to.. most bash users use the tilde `~` and not `$HOME` variable.  Please include that in your answer :)  glenn_jackman suggestion should also work but 90% of the time, i myself type in `cd ~[ENTER]`.  I don't know why I don't take the easier path :P

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I cannot run `cd ~[ENTER]` what should be Enter there?

Comment: The enter key. ;)  I was *trying* to make a spiffo "Enter" key with my stupid brackets.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: So you mean just `cd ~` and then pressing Enter key?

Comment: Yes.  Perhaps the enter key seems like a given but after doing tech support for years, I try to be explicit.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I am new in this Tag and Terminal and I am trying learn the standards and basic, thanks for help.